# how to parse nested json in android studio?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, listview, android-studio

i am working on an android project,i want to display multiple images according to json required data, json consist on nested array. please suggest how to parse nested array data in model class and how to show images in custom layout using base adapter class
below is my json....

```
[
        {
                "post_images":[
                    {
                        "message_image_id":"17",
                        "image_name":"rlvezdcuorfuhkr8nluc",
                            "cdn_public_id":null,   
                        "image_description":null,   
                        "message_id":"24",
                            "width":"960",
                        "height":"959",
                        "comment_count":"1",    
                        "like_count":"0",
                        "unlike_count":"0",
                        "share_count":"0",
                            "description":null,
                        "is_shared_product":"0",
                        "shared_with":"1",
                    }   
                ]
        }
        {
            "post_images":[ 
                    {
                        "message_image_id":"9",
                            "image_name":"pleyat8ghaaocvipvre2",
                            "cdn_public_id":null,
                        "image_description":null,
                        "message_id":"23",
                            "width":"596",
                        "height":"411",
                            "comment_count":"0",
                        "like_count":"0",
                        "unlike_count":"0",
                        "share_count":"0",
                            "description":null,
                        "is_shared_product":"0",    
                        "shared_with":"1",
                    }   
                    {
                        "message_image_id":"10",
                            "image_name":"jjtcdum8kksseuo5cuaa",
                            "cdn_public_id":null,   
                        "image_description":null,
                        "message_id":"23",
                            "width":"588",
                        "height":"567",
                        "comment_count":"0",
                        "like_count":"0",
                        "unlike_count":"0",
                            "share_count":"0",
                        "description":null,
                        "is_shared_product":"0",
                            "shared_with":"1",
                    }   
                    {
                        "message_image_id":"11",
                        "image_name":"w6guovyarum7cnmfxn1u",
                            "cdn_public_id":null,
                        "image_description":null,
                        "message_id":"23",
                            "width":"960",
                        "height":"768",
                            "comment_count":"0",        
                        "like_count":"0",
                        "unlike_count":"0",
                        "share_count":"0",
                            "description":null,
                        "is_shared_product":"0",
                        "shared_with":"1",
                            "is_classified_images":"0"
                    }
                    {   
                        "message_image_id":"12",
                        "image_name":"cir6zphicl6lq4iirz7h",
                            "cdn_public_id":null,
                        "image_description":null,
                        "message_id":"23",
                            "width":"900",
                        "height":"558",
                        "comment_count":"0",
                        "like_count":"0",
                        "unlike_count":"0",
                        "share_count":"0",
                            "description":null,
                        "is_shared_product":"0",
                        "shared_with":"1",
                        }   
                ]
            }
        {
                "post_images":[
                    {
                        "message_image_id":"6",
                        "image_name":"mhajt2jifnkucrmgsk6v",
                            "cdn_public_id":null,
                        "image_description":null,
                        "message_id":"22",
                            "width":"547",
                        "height":"590",
                        "comment_count":"1",
                        "like_count":"0",       
                        "unlike_count":"0",
                        "share_count":"0",
                            "description":null,
                        "is_shared_product":"0",    
                        "shared_with":"1",
                    }
                    {
                        "message_image_id":"7",
                        "image_name":"sxdfvo7qfvewmm85ufsf",
                            "cdn_public_id":null,
                        "image_description":null,
                        "message_id":"22",
                            "width":"596","height":"547",
                        "comment_count":"0",    
                        "like_count":"0",
                        "unlike_count":"0",
                        "share_count":"0",
                            "description":null,
                        "is_shared_product":"0",
                        "shared_with":"1",
                    }
                    {
                        "message_image_id":"8",
                        "image_name":"mrvzu4npy8a4ydl8rsnk",
                            "cdn_public_id":null,
                        "image_description":null,
                        "message_id":"22",
                            "width":"826","height":"562",
                        "comment_count":"0",    
                        "like_count":"0",
                        "unlike_count":"0",
                        "share_count":"0",
                            "description":null,     
                        "is_shared_product":"0",
                        "shared_with":"1",
                        }
            ]
        }

    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I will explain this with the help of an example say this is my JSON :

```
    {  
   "page":1,
   "results":[  
      {  
         "poster_path":"\/sM33SANp9z6rXW8Itn7NnG1GOEs.jpg",
         "adult":false,
         "overview":"In the animal city of Zootopia, a fast-talking fox who's trying to make it big goes on the run when he's framed for a crime he didn't commit. Zootopia's top cop, a self-righteous rabbit, is hot on his tail, but when both become targets of a conspiracy, they're forced to team up and discover even natural enemies can become best friends.",
         "release_date":"2016-02-11",
         "genre_ids":[  
            16,
            12,
            10751,
            35
         ],
         "id":269149,
         "original_title":"Zootopia",
         "original_language":"en",
         "title":"Zootopia",
         "backdrop_path":"\/mhdeE1yShHTaDbJVdWyTlzFvNkr.jpg",
         "popularity":90.776684,
         "vote_count":1099,
         "video":false,
         "vote_average":7.51
      }
   ],
   "total_results":19704,
   "total_pages":986
}
```

I would parse it using JSONObject and JSONArray as following :

```
private ArrayList<MovieDataModel> parseJsonResponse(String jsonData) throws JSONException
        {
            final String RESULTS_LIST = "results";
            final String MOVIE_OVERVIEW = "overview";
            final String MOVIE_TITLE = "title";
            final String MOVIE_IMAGE_THUMBNAIL = "poster_path";
            final String MOVIE_IMAGE = "backdrop_path";
            final String VOTE_AVERAGE = "vote_average";
            final String RELEASE_DATE = "release_date";


            ArrayList<MovieDataModel> movieDataItems = new ArrayList<>();

            JSONObject moviesJsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
            JSONArray movieResults = moviesJsonObject.getJSONArray(RESULTS_LIST);
            for (int i = 0; i < movieResults.length(); i++) {
                StringBuffer IMAGE_URL_SMALL = new StringBuffer(context.getString(R.string.image_url_small));
                StringBuffer IMAGE_URL_LARGE = new StringBuffer(context.getString(R.string.image_url_large));
                JSONObject jsonMovieDataObject = movieResults.getJSONObject(i);
                MovieDataModel movieDataObject = new MovieDataModel();
                movieDataObject.setMovieName(jsonMovieDataObject.getString(MOVIE_TITLE));
                movieDataObject.setMoviePlotSynopsis(jsonMovieDataObject.getString(MOVIE_OVERVIEW));
                movieDataObject.setMovieImage(IMAGE_URL_LARGE.append(jsonMovieDataObject.getString(MOVIE_IMAGE)).toString());
                movieDataObject.setReleaseDate(jsonMovieDataObject.getString(RELEASE_DATE));
                movieDataObject.setVoteAverage(jsonMovieDataObject.getString(VOTE_AVERAGE));
                movieDataObject.setMoviePosterImageThumbnail((IMAGE_URL_SMALL.append(jsonMovieDataObject.getString(MOVIE_IMAGE_THUMBNAIL))).toString());
                movieDataItems.add(movieDataObject);
            }

            return movieDataItems;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check you JSON Response it is not valid. 
Check on http://jsonlint.com/ (Just copy your Response and paste over there and check).

Please check following example here you can get all image path form Your JSON Response.

For Imageview with BaseAdapter just go through "http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/"

JSON Parsing

```
 private void method() throws JSONException {


    JSONArray mainArray = new JSONArray("YOUR JSON RESPONSE");
    JSONArray Array1 = null;
    JSONArray Array2 = null;

    ArrayList<String> mImageArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < mainArray.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject mObject = mainArray.getJSONObject(i);

        Array1 = mObject.getJSONArray("post_images");

        for (int j = 0; j < Array1.length(); j++) {


            JSONObject mObject2 = Array1.getJSONObject(i);

            // here you get image path or name
            String imagePath = mObject2.getString("image_name");
            mImageArrayList.add(imagePath);




        }


    }


}
```